# Convert the format of the dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, formatting

I'm struggling with converting my dataframe from:

```
year    jan    feb    mar    apr    may    jun    jul    aug    sep    oct    nov    dec 
2016    4.5    3.8    5.3    6.5   11.3   13.9   15.3   15.5   14.6    9.8    4.9    5.9    
2017    3.8    5.2    7.3    8.0   12.1   14.4   15.1   14.5   12.5   11.2    5.7    4.1
2018    4.0    2.3    3.8    8.4   12.0   14.8   17.2   15.2   12.4    9.5    7.3    5.8
2019    3.4    6.0    6.8    8.4   10.0   13.2   16.4   15.8   13.1    8.9    5.3    5.1
```

to:

```
month  number
2016-1  4.5
2016-2  3.8
2016-3  5.3
2016-4  6.5
...


...
2019-12 5.1
```

I'd appreciate it if anyone could help!

Comment: Please input the example data to ```dput()``` and post the output.

Comment: I used to think so too, but discovering the obvious solution with `read.table` as shown in my answer really makes this not necessary. OP's data paste thus offers both human and machine readability, whereas dput's really aren't human readable.

Answer (score 0):

Not a super-elegant solution but it gets the job in a sort of easily understood way:

```r
d <- read.table(text=
"year    jan    feb    mar    apr    may    jun    jul    aug    sep    oct    nov    dec
2016    4.5    3.8    5.3    6.5   11.3   13.9   15.3   15.5   14.6    9.8    4.9    5.9
2017    3.8    5.2    7.3    8.0   12.1   14.4   15.1   14.5   12.5   11.2    5.7    4.1
2018    4.0    2.3    3.8    8.4   12.0   14.8   17.2   15.2   12.4    9.5    7.3    5.8
2019    3.4    6.0    6.8    8.4   10.0   13.2   16.4   15.8   13.1    8.9    5.3    5.1
", header=TRUE )

library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

pivot_longer( d, cols=tolower(month.abb), values_to="number" ) %>%
    mutate( month = paste(year,match(name,tolower(month.abb)),sep="-") ) %>%
    select( -year,-name ) %>% relocate(month)
```